# MYSQL Stored procedure not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will instert a record into the database and return the newly created id. If a record with the same name already exists, it should return the id of that record.
This is what I have so far, it works for newly inserted records, but returns nothing if the record already exists.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_tag`(IN `tag_name_in` VARCHAR(255), OUT `tag_id_out` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (tag_name_in); 
    IF ROW_COUNT() = 1 THEN 
        SET tag_id_out = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
    ELSE 
        SELECT id INTO tag_id_out FROM tag WHERE name=tag_name_in; 
    END IF; 
END
```

Comment: Does `tag (name)` id defined as UNIQUE in the table structure?

Comment: *This is what I have so far, it works for newly inserted records, but returns nothing if the record already exists.* I think that your INSERT simply generates unique constraint violation error, and procedure fails.

Comment: @Akina yes tag(name) is UNIQUE, I assumed it would continue executing even if the constraint violation error was thrown. If it doesn't then that may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the reason to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` at all.

```sql
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `insert_tag`(IN `tag_name_in` VARCHAR(255), OUT `tag_id_out` INT) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tag (name) VALUES (tag_name_in); 
    SELECT id INTO tag_id_out FROM tag WHERE name=tag_name_in; 
END
```

Due to the question text `tag (name)` is defined as UNIQUE (maybe even PRIMARY KEY).

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, because of the `IGNORE` part. Both the suggested code and my original code with `IGNORE` work. Thanks.